# How to perform a breadth-first traversal of an expression?

Tags: programming, trees, traversal

*Mathematica* provides functions that perform a depth-first traversal, or which use such a traversal, including: `Scan`, `Count`, `Cases`, `Replace`,  and `Position`.  It is also the standard evaluation order therefore functions Mapped (`Map`, `MapAll`) will evaluate in a depth-first order.

It is quite direct to do this:

```
expr = {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}};

Scan[Print, expr, {0, -1}]
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> {2,3}
>
> {1,{2,3}}
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> {4,5}
>
> {{1,{2,3}},{4,5}}

How can one do a `Scan`-type operation [breadth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_search)?  (Simply storing then reordering the output is not adequate as it doesn't change the order in which expressions are visited.)

`Scan` has the property that it does not build an output expression the way that e.g. `Map` does, which is quite appropriate for breadth-first scans, and conserves memory.

Comment: What do you mean that `Map` and `MapAll` perform a df traversal?

Comment: Convert expression to Graph, then do `BreadthFirstScan`.

Comment: @Rojo A little late but I rewrote the question to hopefully rectify the inaccurate statements.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an expressly iterative solution:

```
bf[f_, x_] := ((f~Scan~#; #~Level~{2})& ~FixedPoint~ {x};)

(*
In[2]:= bf[Print, {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}}]

{{1,{2,3}},{4,5}}
{1,{2,3}}
{4,5}
1
{2,3}
4
5
2
3
*)
```

---

Incorporating Rojo's advice to `Hold` expressions gathered by `Level`:

```
bf[f_, x_] := ( Level[f~Scan~#; #, {2}, Hold] & ~FixedPoint~ {x} ;)
```

Comment: As they always say, Know Your Audience ;)

Comment: I may have to Accept this. :-)

Comment: hmm... you start out with a sad face, but end with a winkey

Comment: +1, you forgot to put the `;)` in the next line. Wink not intended but appropriate

Comment: `bf[Hold, Hold[Print@2]]` leaks. It could be fixed by letting down the audience and changing infix `Level` to `Level[#, {2}, Hold]`

Comment: @Rojo good point, and FYI that's not letting *me* down; I like this just as well: `bf[f_, x_] := ( Level[f~Scan~#; #, {2}, Hold] & ~FixedPoint~ {x} ;)`

Answer (score 18):

```
breadthFirst[expr_] := Flatten[Table[Level[expr, {j}], {j, 0, Depth[expr]}], 1]
```

Running example:

```
expr = {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}};

breadthFirst[expr]

(* Out[14]= {{{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}}, {1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}, 1, {2, 
  3}, 4, 5, 2, 3} *)
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is a simple implementation of a breadth first traversal. It simply maps the function onto each element on the current level and then collects all non-atomic entries into the next level, rinse and repeat.

```
breadthFirstApply[{}, call_] := Null
breadthFirstApply[list_, call_] := (call /@ list;breadthFirstApply[Level[list,{2}], call])
```

Output with your data structure:

```
      breadthFirstApply[{{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}}, Print]
```

> ```
> {1,{2,3}}(*level 1*)
> {4,5} (*level 1*)
> 1 (*level 2*)
> {2,3} (*level 2*)
> 4 (*level 2*)
> 5 (*level 2*)
> 2 (*level 3*)
> 3 (*level 3*)
> ```

Edit: Updated code based on feedback from Rojo

Comment: +1. 2 small comments/questions. 1) Any reason to use `call[#]&` instead of plain `call`? 2) Any difference between `Join@@Select...` and `Level[list, {2}]` apart from `Join@@...` requiring all the sublists to have the same head?

Comment: @Rojo I can't say there was any particular reason for the call[#]& just did it in a hurry, as for Level, I'm just in a mindeset where I didn't consider Level. Thanks for the great feedback, I added the changes to the code.

Comment: :). Now with level I think you don't even need the inner `Select`, because the atoms simply won't be extracted by `Level` since they belong to level 1

Comment: @Rojo I'm rapidly running out of code for you to hack away at. :)

Answer (score 13):

```
expr = {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}};

Do[Scan[Print, expr, {i}], {i, 0, Depth@expr}]
```

> {{1,{2,3}},{4,5}}
>   {1,{2,3}}
>   {4,5}
>   1
>   {2,3}
>   4
>   5
>   2
>   3

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `ReplaceAll` doesn't do breadth first, but depth first pre-order. And apart from it (and maybe `Pick` which I would have to think if it offers something new to the issue) I also don't know how to do .

Comment: @Rojo Would you explain what you wrote about `ReplaceAll`?

Comment: I meant that `ReplaceAll` does a recursive "first the expression and then the arguments` traversal (depth first, pre-order), while most of the other functions do a depth first post-order (first the arguments, then the whole expression). But breath-first I think is different, it would mean traverse one level at a time, http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Animated_BFS.gif

Comment: @Rojo I guess I have my terminology wrong.  I suppose I need to revise the question but I'm too tired to do it now.

Comment: @Rojo just for reference, this would be a BF traversal, correct?: `Table[Scan[Print, expr, {i}], {i, 0, Depth@expr}];`

Comment: I think so. Let's just wait for the computer scientists to come and set us straight

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, that is a breadth-first traversal.

Answer (score 9):

I meant my comment above as a joke, but here's the implementation anyway.

Some ugly recursive code to convert the expression to a `Graph`:

```
ClearAll[treeBuild]
treeBuild[expr_[ops___]] := treeBuild[expr, #] & /@ {ops}
treeBuild[name_, expr_[ops___]] := 
   Module[{node = Unique[expr]}, {name \[DirectedEdge] node,treeBuild[node, #] & /@ {ops}}]
treeBuild[node_, a_] := node \[DirectedEdge] Unique["L" <> ToString[a] <> "$"]
```

Build the `Graph`

```
g = treeBuild[expr] // Flatten;

Graph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name", PlotRangePadding -> 0.25, 
         VertexSize -> Large, VertexStyle -> {List -> Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now the breadth first scan:

```
HighlightGraph[ 
  Graph[g, VertexSize -> Large, VertexStyle -> {List -> Green}], {#}] & /@ 
  Reap[
     BreadthFirstScan[Graph@g,List, {"PrevisitVertex" -> (Sow[#1] &)}];
  ][[2, 1]]//ListAnimate
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A package-ready breadth-first position search, returning positions of a pattern in an expression. It allows top-down and bottom-up breadth-first traversals by setting level specification. It is not exactly the one Mr.Wizard was looking for, as it checks absolute levels rigorously (i.e. all level 4 subparts are checked before any level 3 subpart is visited). Deals with the usual level specifications and can return a limited number of cases if asked for.

```
Options[bfPosition] = {Heads -> True};
bfPosition[expr_, patt_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   bfPosition[expr, patt, {0, ∞}, ∞, opts];
bfPosition[expr_, patt_, level_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   bfPosition[expr, patt, level, ∞, opts];
bfPosition[expr_, patt_, level_, 0 | 0., opts : OptionsPattern[]] = {};
bfPosition[expr_, patt_, level_, n_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; 
   If[MatchQ[level, {_Integer | Infinity, _Integer | Infinity} |
       {_Integer | Infinity} | _Integer | Infinity], True, 
    Message[bfPosition::level, level]; False] := Module[
   {lev, max = Depth@expr, range, c = 0, found, reap},

   (* Normalize level specification *)
   lev = Switch[level /. Infinity -> max,
     {_Integer, _Integer}, level,
     {_Integer}, {First@level, First@level},
     _Integer, {1, level}];
   lev = (Min[#, max] & /@ (lev /. x_?Negative :> Max[(max + 1 + x), 0]));
   range = Range[First@lev, Last@lev, If[Greater @@ lev, -1, 1]];

   (* Check each level until the required amount of matches are found *)
   reap = Last@Reap@Do[
       found = Position[expr, patt, {i, i}, n - c, Heads -> OptionValue@Heads];
       c = c + Length@found;
       Sow@found;
       If[c >= n, Return[]];,
       {i, range}];

   If[reap === {}, {}, Join @@ (First@reap)]
   ];
```

`bfPosition[expr, pattern]` gives a list of the positions at which objects matching `pattern` appear in `expr` by performing a breadth-first search of subparts. `Position[expr, pattern, levelspec]` finds only objects that appear on levels specified by `levelspec`. `Position[expr, pattern, levelspec, n]` gives the positions of the first `n` objects found. `bfPosition` effectively accepts reverse-ordered level specifications that define the order of search in expr: for example `bfPosition[expr, pattern, {∞, 0}]` performs a bottom-up while `bfPosition[expr, pattern, {0, ∞}]` performs a top-down breadth-first search.

Test it:

```
 expr = {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}};
 pos = bfPosition[expr, _, {∞, 0}, Heads -> False];
 If[# === {}, expr, Extract[expr, #]] & /@ pos
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 1, {2, 3}, 4, 5, {1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}, {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}}}
> ```

Note that all level-3 objects (`2`, `3`) are visited before encountering a level-2 leaf (`1`).

`bfPosition` is not like `Position` (`Position` does a depth-first postorder search):

```
bfPosition[expr, _, Heads -> False]
Position[expr, _, Heads -> False]
```

> ```
> {{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}
>
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 2}, {1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2}, {}}
> ```

Find positions using bottom-up or top-down search:

```
bfPosition[expr, _, {∞, 0}, Heads -> False]
bfPosition[expr, _, {0, ∞}, Heads -> False]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1}, {2}, {}}
>
> {{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}
> ```

Find a limited number of occurrences only:

```
bfPosition[expr, _, {∞, 0}, 4, Heads -> False]
bfPosition[expr, _, {0, ∞}, 4, Heads -> False]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}
>
> {{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks very much for this Istvan. However I believe it doesn't work with patterns with Alternatives in them. For example if the '4' in 'expr' is changed to '4->6', then: bfPosition[expr,(Rule|List)[___]] does not give the same result (after sorting) as Position does.

Answer (score 5):

I don't sure this will look as a duplicated version with [Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9266/21532) in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9266/21532),but there are some trick function can make you life ease and simplify that answer.So I post this answer still.

### Build graph by `` GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph `` from any expression

```
expr = Hold[
   Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]];
exprGraph = 
 GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[expr, VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]

### `` Experimental`ListAnimator `` can make a animate without that control.

```
Experimental`ListAnimator[
 HighlightGraph[exprGraph, #, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"] & /@ 
  Reap[BreadthFirstScan[
     exprGraph, {"PrevisitVertex" -> (Sow[#1] &)}]][[2, 1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: This even works in v10.1. Cool. :-)