# How to perform a depth-first preorder traversal of an expression?

Tags: programming, trees, traversal

*Mathematica* provides functions that perform a [depth-first postorder traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order), or which use such a traversal, including: `Scan`, `Count`, `Cases`, `Replace`,  and `Position`.  It is also the standard evaluation order therefore functions Mapped (`Map`, `MapAll`) will evaluate in a depth-first-postorder.

It is quite direct to do this:

```
expr = {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}};

Scan[Print, expr, {0, -1}]
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> {2,3}
>
> {1,{2,3}}
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> {4,5}
>
> {{1,{2,3}},{4,5}}

It is not as obvious how to do a [depth-first **preorder**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) scan.  (Simply storing then reordering the output is not adequate as it doesn't change the order in which expressions are visited.)

`Scan` has the property that it does not build an output expression the way that e.g. `Map` does, and conserves memory.

How can one do a `Scan`-type operation in depth-first **preorder**?

---

Related:

- [How to perform a breadth-first traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9209/121)
- [How to perform a depth-first in-order traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140648/121)

Comment: Related topic: I [have implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700934/why-is-cases-so-slow-here-are-there-any-tricks-to-speed-it-up/8701756#8701756) a special version of `Cases` which performs the depth-first preorder traversal (perhaps not optimally). In that case, this was important to avoid unpacking during the traversal performed by `Cases`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am aware of two general methods.

### ReplaceAll

The only general purpose function I am aware of that visits depth-first preorder is `ReplaceAll`.  One can "scan" a given function such as `Print` as a side-effect by using either `PatternTest` or `Condition`, both of which only match if the return is explicitly `True`.

```
{{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}} /. _?Print -> Null;
```

> {{1,{2,3}},{4,5}}
>   List
>   {1,{2,3}}
>   List
>   1
>   {2,3}
>   List
>   2
>   3
>   {4,5}
>   List
>   4
>   5

`List` is printed because `ReplaceAll` includes Heads whereas `Scan` by default does not.

We cannot use the level specification of `Span` but we can use patterns.  For example:

```
{{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}} /. {_, _} ? Print -> Null;
```

> {{1,{2,3}},{4,5}}
>   {1,{2,3}}
>   {2,3}
>   {4,5}

### Recursive function

This can be done using a recursive function, the purest form of which is:

```
(Print@#; #0 ~Scan~ #)& @ {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}}
```

> {{1,{2,3}},{4,5}}
>   {1,{2,3}}
>   1
>   {2,3}
>   2
>   3
>   {4,5}
>   4
>   5

Though not as fast as `ReplaceAll` this method can be extended more generally, for example to accept a level specification:

```
preorderScan[f_, expr_, {L1_, L2_}] :=
 Module[{rec},
  rec[n_][ex_] := (If[n >= L1, f@ex]; rec[n + 1] ~Scan~ ex);
  rec[n_ /; n > L2][_] = Null;
  rec[0][expr]
 ]

preorderScan[Print, {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}}, {1, 2}]
```

> {1,{2,3}}
>   1
>   {2,3}
>   {4,5}
>   4
>   5

(The function above is an illustration and not intended for reuse.  It does not accept all forms of the standard *levelspec* and it makes no attempt to hold expressions unevaluated.  If requested I can post a more lengthy version that does both.)

Answer (score 18):

Here is a version that uses an explicit stack to avoid recursion.

```
depthFirstPreorder[expr_] := Module[
  {stack = {expr, {}}, el = expr},
  Reap[
    While[stack =!= {},
      {el, stack} = stack;
      Sow[el];
      If[Not[AtomQ[el]],
       Do[stack = {el[[j]], stack}, {j, Length[el], 1, -1}]];
      ];
    ][[2, 1]]
  ]
```

The customary example:

```
expr = {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}};

depthFirstPreorder[expr]

(* Out[16]= {{{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}}, {1, {2, 3}}, 1, {2, 3}, 2, 3, {4, 
  5}, 4, 5} *)
```

Comment: Daniel, I see that this is `Reap`ing expressions; unlike `Scan` this is building an output expression, right?  Is `Sow` simply an example function to "scan" over the expression?  What are the tradeoffs of this method compared to recursion?

Comment: Yes, it builds an output expression. Sow is not an example function but rather is used in a necessary way. One could easily provide for a function to apply to subexpressions, though I did not. Main advantage is for deeply nested expressions because it will not blow up the program's subroutine stack.

Answer (score 9):

Don't know where this should fit. Playing around, this could be a more general approach to the traversal problem. It's probably not best for those traversals that can be done in other ways. Specifically, it has to create the list of indices all at once so it's not memory efficient as `Scan`

```
Module[{tag}, 
 generalScan[fun_, expr_, sortingFun_: RandomSample] := 
  Extract[Unevaluated@expr, If[# === {}, fun[expr]]; #, fun] &~Scan~
   sortingFun[
    Reap[MapIndexed[tag, Hold[expr], Infinity, Heads -> True] /. 
       tag[_, {1, in___}] /; Sow[{in}, tag] :> Null, tag][[-1, 1]]]]
```

This takes a third argument that makes you sort the list of indices to traverse. Defaults to `RandomSample` (hihihi)

```
expr = {{{1, {2}}}, {3, {4}}};

(* Random *)
generalScan[Print, expr]

(* Breadth-first *)
generalScan[Print, expr, Sort]

(* Breadth-first right-left *)
generalScan[Print, expr, SortBy[#, Minus] &]

(* Depth-first preorder *)
generalScan[Print, expr, Part[#, Ordering[PadRight[#]]] &]
```

...

It could be used for other purposes such as traversing a part of a tree. This would only traverse the leftmost branch

```
generalScan[Print, expr, Cases[#, {1 ..}] &]
```

Answer (score 8):

`TreeForm` lays the expression tree out in a depth-first preorder traversal fashion. So observing that using `VertexLabeling -> Tooltip` gives you the expression at that level, we can redefine `Tooltip` using the [Villegas–Gayley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656) trick to print out the expressions as `TreeForm` lays out the tree. Replace `Print` with any desired function.

```
Unprotect@Tooltip;
Tooltip[expr_, label_] /; ! TrueQ[$insideTooltip] :=      
 Block[{$insideTooltip = True},
   If[HoldPattern@label =!= 
        HoldPattern@Network`GraphPlotDump`Private`tp$_, Print[label]];
        Tooltip[expr, label]
    ]
Protect[Tooltip];
TreeForm[{{1, {2, 3}}, {4, 5}}, VertexLabeling -> Tooltip]

(*
{{1,{2,3}},{4,5}}
{1,{2,3}}
1
{2,3}
2
3
{4,5}
4
5
*)
```

Comment: While clever, I wouldn't expect this to maintain the memory conserving performance of `Scan`, which is a fairly significant component of my question.

Answer (score 6):

[My answer to the breadth first scan question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9266/57) (convert your expression to a `Graph` and do a `BreadthFirstScan`) can also be used for the depth first scan (if you have MMA v8). You only need to replace `BreadthFirstScan` by `DepthFirstScan`. The latter is apparently (and luckily in this case) of the pre-order type.

For the code I refer to the answer referenced above. The visualization of the result is as follows:

[image]