# Control over depth-first scan and breadth-first scan

Tags: programming, graphs-and-networks

Is there a way to **conditionally** take control/modify the flow during a depth-first scan or the breadth-first scan ?

Say, **for example**, if a particular node if found, consider it as a leaf-node and continue with the rest of the processing as usual (meaning do not traverse its child-nodes).

Comment: A particular example of what you want to do might be helpful to potential answerers.

Comment: I am trying to find a path in 2D regular grid (GridGraph[{m, n}]), which satisfies some conditions.


I need to explore pathways starting from a node.


I think DFS would be one (quick+suitable for my purpose) way to explore all possible pathways.


But as soon as I see that the current path is NOT a solution, I need the algorithm to stop there and not process the child nodes further.


(I am thinking of using DFS since I find the events very handy)

Can this be done?

Comment: There are ways indicated [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9233/how-to-perform-a-depth-first-preorder-traversal-of-an-expression) for doing a depth first traversal. You could modify one to terminate any given path on encountering a given condition.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9234/1194) that Daniel linked to is easily hacked to include a stop condition, you simply take the recursive function, but filter the next level depending on your stopping criterion.

```
stopCondition[element_] := Length[element] > 1;
(Print@#; #0~Scan~Select[#, stopCondition]) &@{{1, {2, 3}, 0}, {4, 5, 2}, 2}
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent. Like I mentioned, I am relying on events associated with the DFS.

Comment: @myaccount_ram I'm assuming you mean to say that you are using the build-in DepthFirstScan function for scanning graphs? If so you should really update your question to reflect this, and include an example highlight what events you are reliant on.

Comment: Thank you all - I am implementing a modified version of a DFS myself!