# How can I substitute something using only map?

Tags: replacement, map

For example, I have the equation

```
x^2 + y^2 == x*y
```

and I want to apply the rule

```
y -> s*x
```

I can do it easily by

```
x^2 + y^2 == x*y //. y -> s*x
```

But it seems to me it would be possible to use only `Map` to change everything.
How can I do it that way? In other words, I think `Replace` is just a kind of syntactic sugar, and want to know how to express `Replace` by `Map`.

Comment: "I think `Replace` is just a kind of syntactic sugar" - no. No, it's not.

Comment: @J.M. Agree. But perhaps it could be interesting if the OP tells us why he thinks it is

Comment: @J.M Oh then they are totally different?

Comment: I think it would be possible if there is a "function" that changes y to s*x. It seems rules are not the function......

Comment: Yes, they act quite differently; `Map[f, {1, 2}]` will apply the function `f` on the elements of the list `{1, 2}` to yield `{f[1], f[2]}`. That wors differently from `Replace[{1, 2}, 1 -> 5, {1}]` which replaces the `1` in `{1, 2}` with `5`, to yield `{5, 2}`.

Comment: `f[y]=s x; f[v_]:=v; Print[":("]; Map[f,x^2+y^2,Infinity]` Might want to check out `DownValues[f]` to see that this in fact does not avoid rules.

Answer (score 5):

As expressed in the comments, the `Replace` functions are not merely "syntactic sugar" for `Map`.  The two are quite different.  One primary difference is the order in which expressions are visited.  See:
[How to perform a depth-first preorder traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233)
Another is that `Replace` will go inside held expressions, while `Map` does not evaluate:

```
Hold[1 + 2 + 3] /. {2 -> 7}
```

> ```
> Hold[1 + 7 + 3]
> ```

```
Map[Print, Hold[1 + 2 + 3], {2}]
```

> ```
> Hold[Print[1] + Print[2] + Print[3]]
> ```

With the exception of these *important* differences, one can do something resembling a `ReplaceAll` using `MapAll`, like this:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]

f[y] := s*x
f[other_] := other

f //@ (x^2+y^2==x*y)
```

> ```
> x^2 + s^2 x^2 == s x^2
> ```

Comment: Nevertheless, the last use of `//@` just feels like using a pipe wrench to whack nails...

Comment: Oh god Thank you!