# substitution rules excluding subscripted variables

Tags: replacement

Suppose I have an expression containing `p`,`Subscript[p,1]`,`Subscript[p,2]`,etc. I want to replace `p` with a numerical value while keeping the other two variables intact. How can I do it?

If I naively use `/.{p->0.5}` for example, I will get `Subscript[0.5,1]`, `Subscript[0.5,2]` as a result.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You wish to make substitutions in all except `Subscript` expressions I believe.  This can be done by leveraging the precedence of replacement rules, like this:

```
{p, Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]} /. {x_Subscript :> x, p -> 1}
```

> ```
> {1, Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]}
> ```

Due to the [traversal order](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9234/121) of `ReplaceAll` the rule `x_Subscript :> x` acts first, "replacing" any expression with the head `Subscript` by itself.  Since expressions that have already been replaced are not matched again, the second rule `p -> 1` is never applied to these subexpressions.

Answer (score 7):

You could also make one rule that is a bit more specific

```
{p, Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]} //. 
 head_[x___, p, y___] /; head =!= Subscript :> head[x, 0.5, y]
```

-> {0.5, Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]}

This does not work if p is the entire expression. i.e

```
p/.head_[x___, p, y___] /; head =!= Subscript :> head[x, 0.5, y]
```

-> p

In that case you will probably have to add another rule. Note also ReplaceRepeated in the above may make things slower than necessary.

**Side remark**

You could also do something with Block as follows, though this is not replacement but rather evaluation

```
Block[
 {p = 0.5, Subscript},
 SetAttributes[Subscript, HoldAllComplete];
 {p, Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]}
 ]
```

-> {0.5, Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]}

Comment: This also has a problem if `p` exists twice in an expression for the same reason that my answer works.  For example, with expression `(p + p^2)/Subscript[p, 1]`.  I suggest amending your answer to use `//.` but that can be inefficient.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I changed it. I guess in light of the new insights that Mathematica remembers if expressions have changed anyway, the "checking if the expression has changed" step of ReplaceRepeated must take negligable time. I suppose MMA just goes through the expression twice if use //., which is the same as in your answer where you use two rules. But then your rules are simpler, so your solution must be better in terms of speed, and I can see ever more desirable properties of your answer :). Anyway, +1 for you

Comment: That was silly of me. It goes through the expression much more often. Changing

Comment: +1 for the `Block` solution!  A very nice addition.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use level specification in `Replace` :

```
Replace[{p, Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]} , p -> 0.5, 1]
(* {0.5, Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]} *)
```

Comment: I don't think it is reasonable to assume that the replacements should happen on a particular level.  Consider for example: `p^2 + Subscript[p, 1] + Subscript[p, 2]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree it's not the most generic solution.