# Using two rules for the same variable

Tags: replacement, rule

I am a newbie in the field so please not angry.
I am reading the tutorial below and having a problem.
Link: [How to Create and Use Rules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateAndUseRules.html)

From the link:
If you give two rules for the same variable, the Wolfram Language will use only the first rule:

```
In[4]:= 2 x + y /. {x -> 3, x -> 4}
Out[4]= 6 + y
```

Could you explain how Mathematica do the substitution here?
Is this the order of implementation:

1. Substitute `x-> 3` to the expression
2. Substitute `x-> 4` to the expression gotten from No. 1

Comment: As far as I understand it, once a subexpression gets replaced, it can't get replaced again. Try this: `a*b /. {a -> a, a -> 1, b -> c}`. The first replacement just replaces `a` with `a`, but since that expression has already been changed, it is ignored after that, so the `Rule` `a - > 1` is only applied to *other* parts of the expression, and there are no more `a`'s, but `b` gets replaced with `c`. So you're kind of right and kind of not.

Comment: Use a `List` of rule lists. `In[265]:= 2 x + y /. {{x -> 3}, {x -> 4}}

Out[265]= {6 + y, 8 + y}`

Comment: @march is correct that [`ReplaceAll` (`/.`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) doesn't apply several rules to the same part of a given expression. For that case you want to use [`ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html). In your case however this won't chance the output since `x -> 3` changes `x` to be `3` so there is no more `x` for the second rule to match against

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I can't help but feel that this is a dupe (although it's a great question). Does anyone have a link? I'll go check the [Pitfalls](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) thread. If it's *not* there, we might consider adding a post about how exactly `ReplaceAll` works.

Comment: This is also simply bad programming style.  You should be able to eliminate duplicate substitution rules and retain only the one you want.

Comment: @march I agree that this should be added in the common pitfalls thread, especially since this behavior of `ReplaceAll` is somewhat hidden in the "Details" section of the documentation

Comment: Thank you all for these answers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I understand it, once a subexpression gets replaced, it can't get replaced again. Try this:

```
a*b /. {a -> a, a -> 1, b -> c}
```

resulting in

```
a*c
```

The first replacement just replaces `a` with `a`, but since that expression has already been changed, it is ignored after that. So the `Rule` `a -> 1` is only applied to *other* parts of the expression (in this case the `b`), and those other parts don't depend on `a`, so nothing changes. Finally, `b` gets replaced with `c`. (By the way, in somewhat-advanced *Mathematica* programming, this fact can be taken advantage of in many clever ways. [Here is an example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25539/29734) by [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard), provided in the comments.)

So you're kind of right and kind of not. The `Rule`s *are* applied sequentially, but the rules are *not* applied to the *new* expressions resulting from previous replacements.

Here's another interesting example:

```
a b c /. {a -> b, b -> c, c -> d}
% /. {a -> b, b -> c, c -> d}
% /. {a -> b, b -> c, c -> d}
(* b c d *)
(* c d^2 *)
(* d^3 *)
```

In the first case, the `a` instance is replaced by `b`, but it is not in turn replaced by `c`. However, the original `b` *is* replaced by `c`. And so on. To do all of them at once, use `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
a b c //. {a -> b, b -> c, c -> d}
(* d^3 *)
```

(Be careful of this one, because it can run into infinite recursions.) For completeness, note that `ReplaceRepeated` does *not* act the same as a sequence of `ReplaceAll`s if the list of `Rule`s are different:

```
a b c //. {a -> b, c -> d, b -> c}
a b c /. {a -> b} /. {c -> d} /. {b -> c}
(* d^3 *)
(* c^2 d*)
```

Finally, as noted by [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) in a comment, if you *do* want to apply the two rules to get different expressions, do this:

```
2 x + y /. {{x -> 3}, {x -> 4}}
(* {6 + y, 8 + y} *)
```

Alternatively, do

```
2 x + y /. # &/@ {x -> 3, x -> 4}
```

or

```
2 x + y /. List/@{x -> 3, x -> 4}
```

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for the thorough answer! I've got it now. However, I think I need to read and try these more.

Comment: I often use the fact that a given expression will not be replaced twice, e.g. [(25538)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25538/121)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I used to remember after reading the answer above!