# Why does {2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} //. {x_Integer -> Sqrt[x]} evaluate infinite times?

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages

Here is my code.

```
{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} //. {x_Integer -> Sqrt[x]}
```

The pop-up message `ReplaceRepeated::rrlim` suggests that  this rule can be applied an infinite number of times.

I am supposed to get `{Sqrt[2],Sqrt[3],Sqrt[3],Sqrt[2],Sqrt[3],0.09}`

What's wrong with my code here?

Comment: Hint: After the first pass, what is the head of the first list element's (`Sqrt[2]`) contents?

Comment: @ciao,  Power. How to make it work ? {Sqrt[2],Sqrt[3],Sqrt[3],Sqrt[2],Sqrt[3],0.09}

Comment: One way might be `{y : Power[_, _] -> y, x_Integer -> Sqrt[x]}` for the rules. More importantly, do you see *why* the example evaluates infinitely?

Comment: @ciao,`x_Integer`  still assumes Sqrt[2] and Sqrt[3] are Integer.

Comment: That pattern matches the `2` in `Sqrt[2]`, does it not? So that `2` is transformed to `Sqrt[2]`, which is then "inside" the original `Sqrt`, leading to `Sqrt[Sqrt[2]]`. `ReplaceRepeated` is effectively the fixed point of `ReplaceAll`, which will drill into expressions until a pattern match is (or is not) found.

The result you are getting is exactly what you should be getting. You need to provide the pattern to match the parts to be left alone, as in my comment example.

A review of the documentation for the various `Replace` species will be helpful here.

Comment: This works `{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} /. x_Integer -> Sqrt[x]`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci, I thought you misunderstood my question here. Please look at what others had done here.

Comment: Perhaps a better response to @OkkesDulgerci would be to point out that his code changes `9` to `3`, not to `Sqrt[3]` as desired.

Comment: `{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09}  //.  {x___, y_Integer, z___}  :>  {x, Sqrt[y], z}`  is another way to replace only at the first level.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html#20351) specifically states:

> You should be very careful to avoid infinite loops when you use the `//.` operator. The command `x //. x -> x + 1` will, for example, lead to an infinite loop.

Since only the first rule that matches is applied to a given expression you can, as [ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao) commented, use:

```
{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} //. {skip_Power :> skip, x_Integer :> Sqrt[x]}
```

> ```
> {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3], Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], 0.09}
> ```

Recommended reading:

- [How to perform a depth-first preorder traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121)
- [substitution rules excluding subscripted variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25538/121)

Comment: Very nice solution, exactly as was asked in OP. Maybe one can add that some confusion arises due to the fact that `Replace` has *levelspec* option, whereas `ReplaceAll`  and `ReplceRepeated`---no.

Comment: A slight generalization: `list //. {x_Integer :> Sqrt[x],
  skip_?NumericQ :>  With[{x = Simplify[skip]}, If[IntegerQ[x], Sqrt[x], skip]]}`. In case other numeric expression are in the original list.

Answer (score 14):

I think the proper answer here is to use **FixedPoint**, because **//.** dives in to the expression. **Sqrt[2]** contains an integer inside so it replaces it over and over.

`FixedPoint[Replace[#, x_Integer :> Sqrt[x], {1}] &, {2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09}]`

Notice that I specifically said that it should replace at level 1.

Comment: Can you please point to the place in the documentation where it is written that `//.` should dive into subexpressions.

Comment: It is basically doing /. repeatedly until it doesn't change any more. The documentation of /. (ReplaceAll). Which has as first line: *applies a rule or list of rules in an attempt to transform each subpart of an expression expr.*

Comment: @yarchik "expr//.rules effectively applies /. repeatedly, until the results it gets no longer change." (Docs for `ReplaceRepeated`)  See also the [documentation for the error message](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/ReplaceRepeated/rrlim.html)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Why then this `{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} //. {x_ /; (Head[x] == Integer) -> Sqrt[x]}` does not work? Sorry, if it is something obvious.

Comment: it works, but again, it dives deeper in to the expression because you're using //. (or /.)

Comment: @yarchik For the same reason the OP's `{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 0.09} //. {x_Integer -> Sqrt[x]}` fails (since they're equivalent, no?). Maybe you can follow the steps with a print statement inserted: `ReplaceRepeated[{2, 9, 3, 16, 81, 
  0.09}, {x_ /; (Head[If[ListQ[x], Print[FullForm /@ x]]; x] == 
      Integer) :> Sqrt[x]}, MaxIterations -> 4]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, now it is clear. I think Mr.Wizard solution is the closest expression of the OP idea.