# Preserve information in flattening a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a series of lists in the form below:

```
list={ {1,1} , {2,2}, {3,{3,1},{3,2},{31,{31,1},{32,2}}} }
```

Its a nested list which the dimension is changing case to case. I want to manipulate the list to have an output like this:

```
LIST={{1,1},{2,2},{3,3,1},{3,3,2},{3,31,31,1},{3,31,32,2}}
```

I am trying to use this ReplaceList rule

```
list //. {a_, {b___}} :> {a, b}
```

But it is not working at all!! How should I make a list out of this nested list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem: your pattern, `{a_, {b___}}` will only match a list with exactly two elements, the second of which has to be a list. As you can see, there is no such list anywhere in your expression, which is why it doesn't work.

You can correct it as follows:

```
sol = list //. {h__Integer, t__List} :> Map[{h} ~Join~ # &, {t}]
(* {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {{3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {{3, 31, 31, 1}, {3, 31, 32, 2}}}} *)
```

Note that the lists have the correct elements, but are nested. You can again employ rules to "flatten" them out with:

```
FixedPoint[Replace[#, {x__List} :> x, {1, Infinity}] &, sol]
(* {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 31, 31, 1}, {3, 31, 32, 2}} *)
```

Comment: How to get ride of the nests to a certain level? I mean to get a result like this `{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3,1},{3,3,2},{3,31,{31,1}},{3,31,{32,2}}}`

Answer (score 4):

[`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) (short form `//.`) uses a [depth-first preorder traversal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121).  As an alternative you might consider using a depth-first *postorder* traversal, as provided by [`MapAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapAll.html) (short form `//@`).

Because [rm -rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf)'s code goes in the top-down direction he used matching and prepending of multiple integers at once.  Half way through the process the list is transformed into this:

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {{3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 31, {31, 1}, {32, 2}}}}
> ```

This may or may not have been your intention.  For example, his method will expand `{0, 1, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}` into `{{0, 1, 2, 2}, {0, 1, 3, 3}}`.  Suppose you didn't want this, and wanted to expand only list starting with a single atom rather than a sequence?

You might then use something like this:

```
f[{a_?AtomQ, b__List}] := Sequence @@ (Prepend[#, a] & /@ {b})
f[other_] := other

f //@ list
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 31, 31, 1}, {3, 31, 32, 2}}
> ```

And:

```
list2 = {{1, 1}, {0, 1, {2, 2}}, {3, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {31, {31, 1}, {32, 2}}}};

f //@ list2
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {0, 1, {2, 2}}, {3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 31, 31, 1}, {3, 31, 32, 2}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
list = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {31, {31, 1}, {32, 2}}}};

Cases[Level[list //. {x___Integer, a_Integer,  b__List} :> {x, (Prepend[#, a] & /@ {b})}, Infinity], 
     {__Integer}, {1}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 31, 31, 1}, {3, 31, 32, 2}}