# Is there an inequality operator (Less, Greater) for lists of elements (as opposed to elements)?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, inequalities

Like multi-column sorting. For example,

```
{1,3,5} > {1,2,5}
```

would return `True`, while

```
{1,3,5} > {1,5,2}
```

would return `False`.

I'm betting there's a simple term for this and that term would lead straight to some function, but I can't think of the term. It'd be a trivial function to write, but there must be something built-in...

(I'm looking for a predicate I can supply to [this `PriorityQueue` implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31968/efficient-priority-queues/31976#31976).)

Comment: _Tiebreaking_ is a term that just came to mind, but searching it yields no results.

Comment: Look at `OrderedQ`...

Comment: Agh, that was what I was looking for. Still not well-versed in $Mathematica$. I didn't think to read through the `*Q` functions, even after thinking the word "Predicate"—I guess I'd only seen more primitive `*Q` functions so didn't think I'd find my answer there. In case this question might help someone else searching the terms I've used, could you post your comment as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: It's been a long day. Thanks, I'll fix.

Comment: what about {1,3,5} > {1,2,7}? You could make a case for either answer. Or {1,3,5} > {1,1,3,5} ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose using [`Order`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Order.html), assuming equal-length lists.

```
Order[{1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 4}]
Order[{1, 3, 5}, {1, 5, 2}]
Order[{1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 5}]
```

> ```
> -1
>
> 1
>
> 0
> ```

You can assign an infix operator if you wish:

```
CirclePlus = Order;

{1, 3, 5} ⊕ {1, 3, 4}
{1, 3, 5} ⊕ {1, 5, 2}
{1, 3, 5} ⊕ {1, 3, 5}
```

> ```
> -1
>
> 1
>
> 0
> ```

You can convert the numeric output to Boolean as needed, but often it is faster to use it numerically.  An example of conversion:

```
Star = Composition[Negative, Order];

{1, 3, 5} ⋆ {1, 3, 4}
{1, 3, 5} ⋆ {1, 5, 2}
{1, 3, 5} ⋆ {1, 3, 5}
```

> ```
> True
>
> False
>
> False
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
listGreater[l1_, l2_] := OrderedQ@{l2, l1}&& l1 =!= l2
listLess[l1_, l2_] := OrderedQ@{l1, l2}&& l1 =!= l2
listGreaterEqual[l1_, l2_] := OrderedQ@{l2, l1}
listLessEqual[l1_, l2_] := OrderedQ@{l1, l2}

{1, 3, 5}~listGreater~{1, 3, 4}

(* True *)
```