# Searching linked lists that contain lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Following the advice I've read here and other sites, I've been trying to use the Mathematica equivalent of a linked lists...

```
testList = {{a, b}, {{c, d}, {{e, f}, {}}}}
```

Now, I want to see if `{c,d}` is a member of `testList`. How do I do that? MemeberQ doesn't transverse the list recursively and Flatten also nukes the sub lists. The following seems to work but I would expect there to be a cleaner simpler way...

```
memberInLinkedList[{}, _] = False;
memberInLinkedList[l_List, v_] := True /; First[l] == v;
memberInLinkedList[l_List, v_] := memberInLinkedList[Last[l], v];
```

Is there a more eloquent or built-in way to do this? Perhaps a general idiom or package that handles this transparently?

Comment: What exactly is `l` in the original definition of `testList`?

Comment: @Shredderroy I think `l` and `testList` are the same.

Comment: Indeed, sorry about that.

Comment: You could use a head different than `List` for the linked list to avoid the flattening issue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
MemberQ[testList, {c, d}, Infinity]
```

> True

Answer (score 10):

Yet another answer

```
b1[x_] := Module[{f, res},
   f[{x, R_}] = True;
   f[{L_, R_}] := f[R];
   f[#] /. f[{}] -> False
   ] &

Block[{$RecursionLimit = 1*^6, $IterationLimit = 1*^6},
 {
  MemberQ[ll, {86, 99}, Infinity] // timeAvg,
  t7[{86, 99}][ll] // timeAvg,
  b1[{86, 99}][ll] // timeAvg
  }
 ]
```

> {0.0196000, 0.00751200, **0.00321600**}

Your move, Mr. Wizard! :)

Comment: Well that's really weird; I thought I tried this form and it was slower, which surprised me.  I guess failed to properly clear a definition during testing. +1!  Back to testing. :-)

Comment: I can't think of any approach to try to improve this.  You win.

Comment: `b1` works fine with `L1` but not with `L2`: `L=Partition[Range@8,2]; L1=Fold[{#2,#}&,{},L]; L2=Fold[{##}&,{},L]; b1[#][L1]&/@L (*{True,True,True,True}*); b1[#][L2]&/@L (*{f$200[8],f$201[8],f$202[8],f$203[8]}*)`

Comment: @RayKoopman As Mr.Wizard I didn't convert this output to `False`. Now I fix it.

Comment: I still get the same kind of `f$xxx[8]` sequence.

Comment: @RayKoopman Now I understand your question! `b1` does not support reverse ordering. If you want you can change `x` <-> `R_` and `L_` <-> `R_` in the definition.

Comment: There is a slightly simpler version of `b1` which seems to be just as fast and doesn't need iteration/recursion limits to be touched. It does unlike Mr.Wizards `t9` crash the kernel for longer linked lists though (unless it finds a match before the crash). Here it is: `b2[x_] := (# //. {{x, _} -> True, {_, r_} :> r, {} -> False}) &`

Comment: @ybeltukov If something seems too good to be true, it probably isn't.

Answer (score 9):

### Methods revisited

ybeltukov posted a cleaner version of `t7` that made me feel rather silly.  (Thanks ybeltukov; it will teach me to be more careful about clearing definitions while experimenting!)  I can't beat it, so instead I'll try to refine it.  First, several of my functions and his `b1` do not return `False` on a failure to match, so this should be corrected.  Second, one should incorporate extension of `$IterationLimit` into the function.  It would then look something like this:

```
t8[linked_, x_] :=
 Module[{f},
  Block[{$IterationLimit = ∞},
   f[{x, R_}] = True;
   f[{}] = False;
   f[{L_, R_}] := f[R];
   f @ linked
 ]]

t8[ll, {86, 99}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

#### A crash with most methods

I discovered that on longer linked lists all the methods suggested so far cause a kernel crash.  ybeltukov confirmed that this problem also affects version 9.0.1.

Examples:

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomInteger[99, {500000, 2}];
ll = Fold[{#2, #} &, {}, %];

MemberQ[ll, {86, 99}]           (* kernel crash *)

Cases[ll, {86, 99}, -1, 1]      (* kernel crash *)

ll /. {86, 99} :> Return[True]  (* kernel crash *)
```

One way around this problem is to manage a stack manually as Daniel did [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9243/121).

```
t9[linked_, pat_] :=
  Module[{R = linked, L},
    While[R =!= {},
      {L, R} = R;
      If[MatchQ[L, pat], Return @ True];
    ];
    False
  ]
```

Now:

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomInteger[99, {500000, 2}];
ll = Fold[{#2, #} &, {}, %];

t9[ll, {86, 99}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

This is not as fast as `b1`/`t8` however.

---

#### Original answer

If you did not have `MemberQ` you could still walk the tree recursively.  Here are several ways to do that:

```
t1[x_] := MatchQ[#, {x, _} | {_, _?#0}] &

t2[x_][{L_, R_}] := MatchQ[L, x] || t2[x][R]

t3[x_] := Module[{f}, f[{L_, R_}] := MatchQ[L, x] || f[R]; f]

t4[x_] := MatchQ[#[[1]], x] || #0 @ #[[2]] &
```

All functions have the syntax: `tfunc[pattern][linkedlist]`.

Sometimes these are even faster than `MemberQ`:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

SeedRandom[1]
RandomInteger[99, {50000, 2}];
ll = Fold[{#2, #} &, {}, %];

MemberQ[ll, {86, 99}, Infinity] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.01148
> ```

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 1*^6},
 timeAvg @ #[{86, 99}][ll] & /@ {t1, t2, t3, t4}
]
```

> ```
> {0.01812, 0.007112, 0.00612, 0.008736}
> ```

---

#### More experiments

Using the syntax `tfunc[pat, list]` is somewhat faster, i.e. this is faster than `t2`:

```
t5[x_, {L_, R_}] := MatchQ[L, x] || t5[x, R]
```

A bit faster still is shifting this to a form that is iterative:

```
t6[x_, {L_, R_}] /; MatchQ[L, x] = True;
t6[x_, {L_, R_}] := t6[x, R]
```

The fastest I found so far is combining this iterative form with the dedicated function a la `t3`:

```
t7[x_] := 
  Module[{f},
    f[{L_, R_}] /; MatchQ[L, x] = True;
    f[{L_, R_}] := f[R];
    f
  ]
```

Timings for these three variations:

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 1*^6, $IterationLimit = 1*^6},
 {
  t5[{86, 99}, ll] // timeAvg,
  t6[{86, 99}, ll] // timeAvg,
  t7[{86, 99}][ll] // timeAvg
 }
]
```

> ```
> {0.00624, 0.005864, 0.005368}
> ```

I find it fairly impressive that `t7` is twice is fast as `MemberQ` in this application.

Comment: I haven't tried them all but, at least t7 breaks in here when you serach for something that isn't there

Comment: @Rojo Yes; I believe `t6` does as well.  That's what I meant when I said "First, several of my functions and his `b1` do not return False on a failure to match ..."  I posted `t5`/`t6`/`t7` in a hurry and I didn't do a good job.  I also tried the cleaner form and somehow convinced myself it was slower.  I hope that `t8` fixes these problems.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Can you add that crash depends on system stack size? For example on Linux you can run Mathematica as `ulimit -s 65536 && mathematica` and the problem disappears.

Comment: @ybeltukov It will have to wait a couple of days if I do it.  I don't have ulimit in Windows AFAIK so I'd need to use another tool, and I'd like to test it before making claims myself.  I don't mind if you edit this answer to note your findings.

Answer (score 3):

*[Edit: I forgot to include the modified `m2` needed for the `LL`-headed linked lists.  I'm including an improved (faster) version.]*

Here are a couple of ways:

```
m1[l_, pat_] := Catch[l /. pat /; Throw[True] :> Null; False];
m2[l_, pat_] := NestWhile[Last, l, # =!= {} && ! MatchQ[First@#, pat] &] =!= {};
```

[Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) suggests in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica/25474#25474) using a special head for linked lists if the elements of the linked list are to be lists themselves.  For example,

```
testLL = LL[{a, b}, LL[{c, d}, LL[{e, f}, LL[]]]]
```

One can then use `Flatten` to get a flat expression:

```
Flatten[testLL, Infinity, LL]
(* LL[{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}] *)
```

Then `MemberQ` (and other such functions) can be used more or less normally:

```
MemberQ[Flatten[testLL, Infinity, LL], {c, d}]
(* True *)
```

If `LL` has the attribute `HoldAllComplete`, as in Leonid Shifrin's answer, we can mark the end of the linked list with `Throw` like this:

```
testLL2 = LL[{a, b}, LL[{c, d}, LL[{e, f}, LL[Throw["endLL"]]]]]
```

Then we can modify `m2` as follows:

```
m2LL[l_, pat_] :=
  Catch[NestWhile[Last, l, ! MatchQ[First@#, pat] &]; True] /. "EndLL" -> False
```

If `NestWhile` gets to the end of the linked list, `First@#` will execute the `Throw`.

**Timing tests**

Using [Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) data (updated to include `Throw["EndLL"]` to mark the end of the list `ll2`):

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomInteger[99, {50000, 2}];
ll = Fold[{#2, #} &, {}, data];
ClearAll[LL];
SetAttributes[LL, HoldAllComplete];
ll2 = Fold[LL[#2, #] &, LL[Throw["EndLL"]], data];
```

Timing:

```
m1[ll, {86, 99}] // timeAvg
m2[ll, {86, 99}] // timeAvg
MemberQ[ll, {86, 99}, Infinity] // timeAvg
```

> 0.00949383
>   0.0142940
>   0.0301806

Below are (updated) timings on the `LL` linked lists.  It is interesting that `MemberQ` with `Flatten` is faster than `MemberQ` with a level spec. of `Infinity`.

```
m1[ll2, {86, 99}] // timeAvg
m2LL[ll2, {86, 99}] // timeAvg
MemberQ[Flatten[ll2, Infinity, LL], {86, 99}] // timeAvg
```

> 0.00865924
>   0.01107858
>   0.0227578

Mr.Wizard's [`t7`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32134/searching-linked-lists-that-contain-lists/32151#32151) is about as fast as `m1`.  A comparison with `MemberQ` is included.

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 1*^6, $IterationLimit = 1*^6}, 
 t7[{86, 99}][ll] // timeAvg]
```

> 0.00860823

But `t7` is faster than `m1` on patterns that don't match (or match near the end):

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 1*^6, $IterationLimit = 1*^6}, 
 t7[{86, 999}][ll] // timeAvg]
m1[ll2, {86, 999}] // timeAvg
```

> 0.064016
>   0.074637

(Update: Of course @ybeltukov's `b1` beats both `t7` and `m1`.)

Comment: +1 for `m1` -- very nice :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Thanks!  Nesting `Last` was conceptually appealing, too, and it avoids having to deal with recursion limit (not particularly important in this case).  Your recursive approach is clearly superior.