# How can I name patterns in a Switch expression?

Tags: pattern-matching, conditional

Suppose I have an expression and want to match it against successive patterns and return an expression corresponding to the first pattern that matched.  In that case, I can use

```
Switch[expr,
  pat1, val1,
  pat2, val2,
  …]
```

For example,

```
Switch[x,
  _Integer, "This is an integer"],
  _Real , "This is a real"],
  _, "This is something else"]
```

However, the `vali` cannot refer to parts of the `pati` by name. i.e. I cannot do:

```
Switch[x,
  i_Integer, ToString[i] <> " is an integer",
  x_Real , ToString[x] <> " is a real",
  e_, ToString[e] <> " is something else"]
```

Ocaml has the `match` function, which is used as:

```
match expr in:
| pat1 -> val1
| pat2 -> val2
...
```

where the `vali` can refer to named parts of the `pati`.  How can this most elegantly be accomplished in Mathematica?

Comment: I _think_ a better example should use named _parts_ (not the whole expression). Otherwise the problem is trivially solved by `Switch[x, _Integer, ToString[x] <> " is an integer",...]`

Answer (score 13):

I recently realised that the Replace function essentially solves this problem, but it is not the sort of function you tend to associate with conditional constructs.  It also might surprise readers of the code, as it is not a common idiom.  This solution is:

```
Replace[expr,
  {pat1 :> val1,
   pat2 :> val2,
   _ :> valD}]
```

e.g.

```
Replace[x,
  {i_Integer :> ToString[i] <> " is an integer",
   x_Real :> ToString[x] <> " is a real",
   e_ :> ToString[e] <> " is something else"}]
```

It might be useful to define this as a new function which automatically added the default pattern to raise an error in case you forget.

I have sometimes seem `/. (ReplaceAll)` used for this, but the syntax is quite different from Switch, and it also unnecessarily descends into subexpressions if you forget to add the default pattern, which could lead to hard-to-debug errors.

Comment: Replace _is_ a really common idiom (in my experience it's much more common than Switch) and should really be preferred to ReplaceAll, which I tend to avoid as much as possible because of the performance implications.

Comment: @Carlo I use `ReplaceAll` for this when I know it will match so it shouldn't recurse down. That's mainly because it has the short form `/.` with a nice precedence, and while I'd like to use `Replace`, avoiding [] or () is usually nice

Answer (score 6):

I like your elegant answer, and...

```
Switch[#, pat : _Integer /; (val = pat; True), Print[val, " is integer"],
   pat : _Real /; (val = pat; True), Print[val, " is real"], 
   pat_ /; (val = pat; True), Print[val, " is none of the above"]] & /@ {1, 1.1, a}

(*

1 is integer
1.1 is real
a is none of the above

*)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this situation I might prefer to define this as a separate function.

```
whatIsThis[x_Integer] := ToString[x] <> " is an Integer."
whatIsThis[x_Real] := ToString[x] <> " is a Real."
whatIsThis[x_] := ToString[x] <> " is something else."


In[4]:= whatIsThis[4]

Out[4]= "4 is an Integer."

In[5]:= whatIsThis[4.1]

Out[5]= "4.1 is a Real."

In[6]:= whatIsThis["Spaghetti"]

Out[6]= "Spaghetti is something else."
```

Mathematica will try to apply the most specific definition.

Answer (score 0):

In line with beliarius's comment your particular example might also be realized with:

```
ToString[#] <>
 Switch[#,
  _Integer, " is an integer",
  _Real, " is a real",
  _, " is something else"] & /@ {1, 1.5, Pi}
```

> ```
> {"1 is an integer", "1.5 is a real", "Pi is something else"}
> ```

I contest your assertion that using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) is incorrect.  Because of how it [traverses expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121) it will always attempt to match the entire expression first, therefore if you include the *else* pattern `_` it will not "look" at deeper levels.  Again applied to the specific example:

```
ToString[#] <> (# /. {
      _Integer -> " is an integer",
      _Real    -> " is a real",
      _        -> " is something else"
    }) & /@ {1, 1.5, Pi}
```

> ```
> {"1 is an integer", "1.5 is a real", "Pi is something else"}
> ```

Unlike this example pattern matching can be used for [destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/mathematica-destructuring/8399#8399) so its use extends far beyond `Switch`.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own `smthSwitch`:

```
SetAttributes[BindSwitch, HoldRest];

BindSwitch[expr_
, form_ , case_
, rest___] :=
With[{attempt = Cases[expr, form :> case, {0}]},
If[attempt === {}
, BindSwitch[expr, rest]
, First@attempt]]
```

Example:

```
BindSwitch[RandomChoice@Join[Range@4, N /@ Range@4, {n}]
,    x_Real , ToString@x <> " is a real"
, x_Integer , ToString@x <> " is an integer"
,        x_ , ToString@x <> " is neither real nor integer"] <> "."
```

Standard color mark-up for patterns is probably more difficult to implement, though. @IanHinder's solution is free from this issue but this one allows you to add named pattern-based test into existing `Switch`es faster.

Note that control flow is safe: `case` is never evaluated until there's a match.

There's no error-checks for incomplete `BindSwitch` expressions but it's easy to add those you'd feel comfortable with.