# Wrapping long strings at word breaks

Tags: string-manipulation

My code ([`PostScriptForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101954/looking-for-postscriptform-or-forthform-to-print-expressions-as-rpn-code)) returns a long string, about 7k characters, in which there are eight deliberate “\r\n” ‘paragraph’ breaks.

Copying the long string into a text editor reveals “\\r” line breaks at the word breaks immediately prior to column 72. These are not wanted. But I would like “\r” (so without the visible back-slash) line breaks at the word break immediately prior to column 250.

Please, is this trivial in Mathematica? There seems not to be a “StringWrap” function—is there anything conceptually similar?

#### Update

I find the idea of using `InsertLineBreaks` appealing, even though it is available only in V10.1 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I correctly understand what you are asking, but I tried the following:

```
fox = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. ";
longFox[n_] := StringJoin[Table[fox, {n}]]
long = longFox[10];
StringLength[long]
```

> `460`

```
pw = CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "PageWidth"];
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "PageWidth"] = 300 72;
Print[Style[InsertLinebreaks[long, 240], "Text"]];
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "PageWidth"] = pw;
```

I then copied and pasted the the contents of the `Print` cell produced by the code into my text editor and the results were two lines of text, the 1st being 239 characters long and 2nd being 220 characters long.

I did this with V10.3.0 running on OS X 10.10.2. I state this because what happens with copy and paste may have OS dependencies.

This seems rather cumbersome to me, so I wouldn't be surprised that if somebody came up with a simpler method than this. Something based on `Export` might be such a simpler approach, but I did not explore in that direction because you seem to be specifically asking for something that works with copy and paste.

#### Update

Here is code using `Export` that I think will work with V.9.

```
makeLine[max_, size_: 0, line_: {}] :=
  Module[{word, chars = size,},
    If[Length[words] < 1, Return[StringRiffle[line]]];
    word = First[words];
    chars = size + StringLength[word] + 1;
    If[chars > max, Return[StringRiffle[line]]];
    words = Rest[words]; 
    makeLine[max, chars, Append[line, word]]]

makeLines[s_String, max_Integer: 78] /; max > 0 :=
  Block[{words, lines = {}},
    words = StringSplit[s];
    If[Max[Length /@ words] > max, Return[{s}]];
    While[Length[words] > 0, AppendTo[lines, makeLine[max]]];
    lines]

Export[
  FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "long.txt"}], 
  makeLines[long, 240], 
  "Lines"]
```

The `Export` expression writes the long string out to the desktop as two strings, the 1st being 239 characters long and 2nd being 220 characters long.

Comment: That doesn't work in version 9.0; and google doesn't know about “InsertLinebreaks”.
https://www.google.com/search?q=Mathematica+%2BInsertLinebreaks
I will investigate `Export`, for which thank you.

Comment: Well, `Export["filePathAndName.txt", longString]` exports the string to a file without the wrap-at-72 characters: progress, thank you.

Comment: @jdaw1.[`InsertLinebreaks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InsertLinebreaks.html) arrived with V10.1. That's why I thought it important to mention the version I was running.

Comment: Thank you: put 'InsertLinebreaks' in an answer, and I'll say it is the answer. I need to save some pennies to buy the upgrade.

Comment: @jdaw1. You did not find my update useful?

Comment: Ticked. Thank you.