# why Level does not sort output according to their levels

Tags: functions, traversal

Consider this example:

```
Level[a + f[x, y^n], {0, Infinity}]

(*{a, x, y, n, y^n, f[x, y^n], a + f[x, y^n]}*)
```

Why the output is sorted in this way. why not following their levels? I was expecting to get:

```
(*{a + f[x, y^n], a, f[x, y^n], x, y^n, y, n}*)
```

Comment: Details&Options: "Level traverses expressions in depth-first order, so that the subexpressions in the final list are ordered lexicographically by their indices.". So in your case use: `Flatten[Table[Level[#, {i}], {i, 0, Depth[#]}]] &`

Comment: @Kuba can you let me know how to get the indices of all Level output so that I can understand waht you mean by ordered lexicographically by their indices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Kuba comments [`Level`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Level.html) follows the standard expression traversal order:

> `Level` traverses expressions in depth-first order, so that the subexpressions in the final list are ordered lexicographically by their indices.

This is actually a [depth-first postorder traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_traversal).
It is the normal order in which expressions are evaluated in *Mathematica*:

```
echo[x_] := (Print@x; x)

expr = a + f[x, y^n];

Map[echo, HoldForm @@ {expr}, {1, -1}]

ReleaseHold[%];
```

> ```
> echo[echo[a] + echo[f[echo[x], echo[echo[y]^echo[n]]]]]
> ```
>
> a
>      x
>      y
>      n
>      y^n
>      f[x,y^n]
>      a+f[x,y^n]

It is used by nearly all System traversal functions, e.g.:

```
Scan[Print, expr, {0, -1}]  (* same output as above; omitted *)

Cases[expr, _, {0, -1}]

expr ~Extract~ Position[expr, _, {0, -1}, Heads -> False]
```

> ```
> {a, x, y, n, y^n, f[x, y^n], a + f[x, y^n]}
>
> {a, x, y, n, y^n, f[x, y^n], a + f[x, y^n]}
> ```

A notable exception is [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) which uses a depth-first preorder traversal.  See:

- [How to perform a depth-first preorder traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121)

You are interested in a breadth-first traversal; see:

- [How to perform a breadth-first traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9209/121)

For an understanding of levels as used by *Mathematica* see the excellent illustrations in answer to:

- [Levels: how do they work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/121)

  Don't miss [Rahul Narain's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15591/121); while less popular than David's it is concise and accurate.

---

#### Solution to implied problem

Although I hope the information above including the linked Q&A's will give you the knowledge to solve the implied problem yourself here is my take on Kuba's code:

```
expr = a + f[x, y^n];

Array[expr ~Level~ {#} &, Depth @ expr, 0, Join]
```

> ```
> {a + f[x, y^n], a, f[x, y^n], x, y^n, y, n}
> ```

And a solution using WReach's `bf` function from the link above:

```
Reap[Sow ~bf~ expr][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {a + f[x, y^n], a, f[x, y^n], x, y^n, y, n}
> ```