# How does pattern matching in expression work?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, trees

I have been trying to understand how mathematica does pattern matching:

```
{Sin[x] + 1} /. Sin -> Cos
```

returns

```
Cos[x] + 1
```

I am guessing that the program searches for the expression in the expression tree and then replaces the pattern once it finds it.

Thanks

Comment: From the documentation of `ReplaceAll`: ReplaceAll looks at each part of expr, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to the next part of expr. The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part or on any of its subparts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have read the documentation. I wanted to know how does it `look at each part of the expresison` does it traverse down the expression tree or it has some other mechanism?

Comment: It performs a DFS of the expression tree. (I am not 100% sure since I cannot find an official source)

Comment: @happyfish It is not always DFS. It is DFS for functions like `Replace`, `Cases`, etc. For `ReplaceAll` it is actually BFS.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for the information! I can't see how BFS is performed with tracing functions (only showing how mma read the expression with DFS, and the replacement is done in one step). Would you mind sharing some details on this observation?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I think `ReplaceAll` is *not* a BFS but rather a depth-first preorder traversal?

Comment: @happyfish these might interest you: [(9209)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9209/121), [(9233)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: @happyfish I wrote about this in [my book](http://mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node456.html). A few other relevant links are [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836790/why-do-replace-and-replaceall-give-different-results-even-when-only-one-rule-and) and [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56010/using-replaceall-to-replace-a-head/56062#56062).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You may be right.