# How to perform a depth-first in-order traversal of an expression?

Tags: trees, traversal

To complement my earlier questions:

- [How to perform a breadth-first traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9209/121)
- [How to perform a depth-first preorder traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121)

I would now like to ask: how to perform a depth-first *in-order* traversal?

Wikipedia gives this illustration of the depth-first in-order traversal:

[image]

The output is A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I.

I believe this traversal applies only to binary trees.

Here is an expression to experiment with, using `Null` for missing leaves.

```
tree = "F"["B"["A", "D"["C", "E"]], "G"[Null, "I"["H", Null]]];
```

I am interested in efficiency and elegance.

Comment: Can you define in-order traversal for a generic tree (not necessarily binary)? What would that mean?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Good question.  I cannot.  I found the example in isolation interesting and wondered if there were already *Mathematica* functions that implement this, or other standard methods.  The Wikipedia description applies to a binary tree, and I don't think this generalizes to an arbitrary number of leaves, as it visits the root node between left and right branches.

Comment: For the GIH branch, how does one decide which is left and which is right?

Comment: @wxffles It was a quick fix so I self-answered instead of deleting.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, as left and right branches have been assigned an order, why can't 3 or more branches be similarly ordered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Recursion

```
tree = "F"["B"["A", "D"["C", "E"]], "G"[Null, "I"["H", Null]]];

dfio[f_][Null | a_~r_~b_] := Scan[dfio[f], {a, r, b}]
dfio[f_][x_] := f[x]

dfio[Print][tree]
```

> A
>
> B
>
> C
>
> D
>
> E
>
> F
>
> G
>
> H
>
> I

### Stack

[Daniel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) showed how to [manually manage a stack](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9243/121).  Applying his method to this traversal:

```
dfioStack[f_, expr_] :=
  Module[ {stack = {expr, {}}, el = expr},
    While[ stack =!= {},
      {el, stack} = stack;
      If[ Length@el === 2,
        Do[ stack = {el[[j]], stack}, {j, {2, 0, 1}}],
        If[ el =!= Null, f @ el]
      ]
    ]
  ]

dfioStack[Print, tree]  (* same output as above *)
```